# Getting excel filename in ssis

Tags: ssis

I was wondering if anyone could help me with getting the excel (source) filename on my destination database in ssis. The database table has a column called filename (which is equal to the excel filename). Having the filename will help me with my audits. Note: I'm not a vb script person but if vb is the only way out, I'll appreciate sample script as I would have to use that in my logic. Thanks

Comment: Which version of SSIS? Also, how does your package determine what Excel file to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a "Derived Column" component and add a new column that contains the wanted property. I guess that you want to add a derived column that will store the "FileName" or "ConnectionString" property of your Excel Connection.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend saving the file as a CSV for multiple reasons. If it is a CSV file, you could create a flat file source for it. Then right click on the item and go to "Show Advanced Editor..." Click on the "Component Properties" tab and go to "Custom Properties" at the bottom. There is a field caled "FileNameColumnName." For the value, put the name of what column you want to store the file name in. Then, the that field will be available for your destination.

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2010/03/31/filenamecolumnname-property-flat-file-source-adapter-ssis-nugget.aspx